# how to fetch specific type of files (*.gz) in ANSIBLE

Tags: ansible, fetch

inventory file

```
user1@server1 ansible_ssh_user=user1 ansible_host=server1
user2@server2 ansible_ssh_user=user2 ansible_host=server2
```

test_plabook.yml

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: fetch files
      fetch:
        src: /path/to/src/dir/*.gz
        dest: /path/to/dest/dir/{{ inventory_hostname}}/
        flat: yes
```

in the source directory i have many files ending with .gz (*.gz). i wanted to fetch them all. how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a variable to the list of remote files that match, with for example:

```
- name: Recursively find /tmp files older than 2 days
  find:
    paths: /path/to/src/dir/
    type: file
    patterns: "*.gz"
  register: files_to_fetch
```

or with:

```
- shell: "(cd /path/to/src/dir/ ; find . -type f -name '*.gz')"
  register: files_to_fetch
```

Then apply your fetch with the items:

```
- name: fetch files
  fetch:
    src: /path/to/src/dir/{{item}}
    dest: /path/to/dest/dir/{{item}}
    flat: yes
  with_items: "{{ files_to_fetch }}"
```

or if you opted for the second solution:

```
  with_items: "{{ files_to_fetch.stdout_lines }}"
```

The first solution being far better in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks rolf82 for the solution. i used find module to resolve my case